# Comparing Two Timestamps Within a Second

Tags: shell, unix, timestamp

I am writing a shell script that parses a CSV file and performs some calculations.

The timestamps are in the form: `HH:MM:SSS.sss` and stored in variables: `$t2` and `$t1`.

I would like to know the difference between the two stamps (it will always be less than one second) and report this as `$t3` in seconds (ie: `0.020`)

```
t3=$t2-$t1
```

But the above code is just printing the two variable with a minus sign between - how do I compare the two timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a funky way to do it! Strip off all the whole seconds to get the milliseconds. Do the subtraction. If result has gone negative it's because the seconds overflowed, so add back in 1000ms. Slot a decimal point on the front to make seconds from milliseconds.

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
t1="00:00:02.001"
t2="00:00:03.081"
ms1=${t1/*\./}
ms2=${t2/*\./}
t3=$((10#$ms2-10#$ms1))
[[ $t3 < 0 ]] && t3=$((t3+1000))
t3=$(echo "scale=3; $t3/1000"|bc)
echo $t3
```

Comment: That almost worked, I go the following error: `./parser.sh: 081: value too great for base (error token is "081")` - any ideas?

Comment: Try running the script using "bash -xv ./parser.sh" to turn on debugging.

Comment: Copy the script and try again please, I seem to have lost a slash in the translation on lines 3 and 4.

Comment: What values do you have for t1 and t2? Can you add a line after ms1 is calculated that says "echo $ms1" and another one after ms2 is calculated that says "echo $ms2"

Comment: When it falls over `ms1=061` and `ms2=081`.  So it is stopping on the fifth line of your code.

Comment: It does not seem to like anything between 080 and 099 and producing the value too great error.

Comment: Ok, it was interpreting the leading zero in "061" and "081" as octal. I have put a "10#" on the front of each in the line starting "t3=" so it knows the numbers are decimal. Try copying again, sorry I was wrong first time!

Comment: Magic - perfect solution for what I was looking to do!  Thanks @Mark!

Comment: I had to edit it one more time - sorry! The floating point division needs to be done in "bc" at the second to last line, else the decimal point may be in wrong place after the octal issue. I am going to go back to bed - I'm having a bad day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk maths to compute this difference in 2 timestamps after converting both timestamps to their milli-second value:

```
t1=04:13:32.234
t2=04:13:32.258
awk -F '[ :.]+' '{
     t1=($1*60*60 + $2*60 + $3)*1000 + $4
     t2=($5*60*60 + $6*60 + $7)*1000 + $8
     print (t2-t1)/60}' <<< "$t1 $t2"
0.4
```

**Formula used for conversion:**

```
timestamp value (ms) = (hour * 60 * 60 + minute * 60 + second ) * 1000 + milli-second
```